# WooCommerce print order automatically

Tags: woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I already created the WooCommerce store and works fine for the restaurant but now I want to connect the store to my personal printer where if any customer makes an order the print will automatically come.

I check few options

https://www.simbahosting.co.uk/s3/product/woocommerce-automatic-order-printing/
https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-google-cloud-print/21129093

where the printer is connected to google cloud services but I do not want to use that option. I want to do it programmatically.

Any Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some Woocommerce invoice plugin ?

If yes, you could use a automatic PDF output then make a batch file (or a software like FolderMill) to automatic print pdf with your printer.

Comment: hi which Woocommerce invoice plugin has an option to connect with foldermill

Comment: Hi, you should go for [Woocommerce PDF Invoice Packings Slips](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/ ) . Then take their extension to autosave invoice on dropbox. Then with FolderMill, you set up the dropbox folder to be printed

Comment: it will print single or all pdf from Dropbox as i want the print immediately .

Comment: Each time a PDF file will be on the folder, FolderMill will print it (you can also setup the delay before)

Comment: ok but how to delete after printing for example if order A comes print the pdf then later order B comes then it will print both PDF yes?

Comment: Nope, each time a PDF file is printed, you can configure FolderMill to delete this pdf OR to be moved in another folder "Processed" for example. Like that, invoice will not be printed twice and if something happens, you always can go to the processed folder and print it again

Comment: ok let me try and if any issue let u know thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

A little late perhaps! Anyway you have also Automatic Email Manager which will send to printer any email w/o attachments, or save on disk,... It runs on Windows background: https://www.automatic-email-manager.com/